# ChartJS Bar Graph Gap

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS to create a simple, static bar graph.  As you can see in the picture, there is a small gap between the first x-value (January) and the y-axis.  Is there a way to remove that gap and have the first x-axis value start/hug at the y-axis (point: 0,0)?  I've looked all over the ChartJS docs and everything I've tried just doesn't work.  From my research it seems you should be able to implement this via the options object but I'm at a loss.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a demo using fiddle, so that would be helpful for people to analyze and fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the below option for chart. It will work

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales : {
            xAxes : [{
                barPercentage : 1,
                categoryPercentage : 1
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

[**Sample-Code**]

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart1");
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};
    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales : {
            xAxes : [{
                barPercentage : 1,
                categoryPercentage : 1
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This works great, thank you!  Is there a way, though, to only make the very first value hug the y-axis and then all additional values would have a small space between them? @SanjayDutt

Comment: @dannyk Yeah, That is the problem with barPercentage it will set for all bars. If I find a solution I will post it..

Comment: OK that sounds good to me.  Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: With chart.js 3.x I found it necessary to set the bar and category percentages in the dataset rather than the X-axis options.